# Get column names and values in for loop PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get all column names and values from a specific table.
The fields in this table aren't fixed, so sometimes there will be added one field by the user and they also can be removed. What I want to do is retrieve all column names and getting the values of it. As far as I am now is retrieving the column names and getting one value out of it. I know why I get this result, but I don'tknow how to fix it.

```
//I edited this sql, normally the table value and id are variable
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$_POST['moduleName']." WHERE modItemID= ".$_POST['modItemID']; 
$query = mysql_query($sql); 
$columns = mysql_num_fields($query); 
for($i = 1; $i < $columns; $i++) { 

//read field name
  $fieldName = mysql_field_name($query,$i);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query,$i)){
    echo $fieldName."=".$row[$fieldName];   
  }

}
```

result:
naam=Ketting

Comment: write the query properly

Comment: inb4 `dont use mysql, use PDO or mysqli`

Comment: is it a typo you missed a `"`?

Answer (score 7):

Actually really easy solution to your problem would be to use foreach loop, like so:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    foreach($row as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "$key=$value";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array. You can use a `foreach` loop to retreive the key=>value of each item in the array.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE modItemID= 14"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql); 
$columns = mysql_num_fields($query); 
for($i = 1; $i < $columns; $i++) { 

//read field name
  $fieldName = mysql_field_name($query,$i);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query,$i)){
    foreach($row as $column=>$value) {
      echo "$column = $value\n";
    }
    echo $fieldName."=".$row[$fieldName];   
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just didn't know what I had to use to make it work.

Comment: While the above code gives you what you want and should work well, having a variable number of columns which are added / deleted by a user sounds like a fairly bad idea. Better to have a table which can contain multiple rows for each user, and those rows can be added / deleted as required.

Answer (score 0):

Just Put your Database name,username,password 
and table name.

You get all data from your main database (with column name)

```
<?php 

function qry($q){

    global $qry;
    try {   
    $host = "?";
    $dbname = "?";
    $username = "?";
    $password = "?";
    $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; 
    dbname=$dbname","$username","$password");
}
catch (Exception $e) {

    echo "ERROR ".$e->getMEssage();

}

    $qry = $dbcon->query($q);
    $qry->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ);

    return $qry;

}


echo "<table>";

/*Get Colums Names in table row */
$columns = array();

$qry1= qry("SHOW COLUMNS FROM Your_table_name");

while (@$column = $qry1->fetch()->Field) {
    echo "<td>".$column."</td>";
    $columns[] = $column;

}

echo "<tr>";

/* Fetch all data into a html table *

$qry2 = qry("SELECT * FROM Your_table_name");

while ( $details = $qry2->fetch()) {

    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($columns as $c_name) {
    echo "<td>".$details->$c_name."</td>";

}

}

echo "</table>";

?>
```