# if mysql any field is empty then show a word like null

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to know that, if there is any empty field then display null in retrieve form. i mean,

---

name----------age----------country

---

xyz----------"  "---------usa

---

so, the form will show

name: xyz

age: show null

country: usa

```
<?php
$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';


$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if(! $conn ) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$No=$_GET['No'];
$sql = "SELECT * from tablename where Name='$Name'";
mysql_select_db('dbname');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval ) {
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
 }

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

   ?>


 <table width="100%"><tr><td>
 <table>
 <tr>
 <tr><td class="a" style="width:20%">Name</td><td style="width:20%"  class="a"><a class="res" ><?php echo $row['Name'];?></a></td></tr>
 <tr><td class="a" style="width:20%">age</td><td style="width:20%"   class="a"><a class="res"><?php echo $row['age'];?></a></td></tr>
 <tr><td class="a" style="width:20%">country</td><td style="width:20%"  class="a"><a class="res"><?php echo $row['country'];?></a></td></tr>
 </tr>
 </table>

 <?php
 }


    mysql_close($conn);
 ?>`
```

Comment: "Why?"  This seems to potentially be a bad design.  When the user goes to save, you then have to convert the null text back to the correct data type, or drop the value.  better off leaving it blank as it was when the form was first loaded/entered saved etc...Technically you can't show null; as null is the absence of data.  All you can really do is show empty set `''`  now in SQL you could coalesce each value selected such as coalesce(age,'NULL') (assuming similar data types) to return the world null.

Comment: ok, then if any field is empty then it will show that, i mean if name or country also empty then also show the null

Comment: `SELECT coalesce(Name, 'NULL') as name, coalesce(age,'NULL') as Age coalesce(country, 'NULL') as country from tablename` but I don't recommend it. displaying null to the end user just seems like bad form; and all the overhead of sanitizing the data for the correct data type.  Yes, I'm showing you how; and cautioning against it.  but if age is numeric data type this will throw an error.

Comment: its only for admin end, so that they can edit it in next level

Comment: and by the way, i do not have any idea about this code, can your rewrite the code with mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just test if the result is empty and if it is show Null.

```
<?php if ($row['Name'] != '') {
    echo $row['Name'];
} else {
    echo "Null";
}?>
```

Comment: its working, but need a crucial one, because for this code i have to write a long script. there is almost 300 field.....

Comment: then iterate field by index instead of name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583367/get-column-names-and-values-in-for-loop-php  You've shown no real understanding of SQL or PHP here.  I'll be backing out of this question at this time as it's mutated into a second question which will likely continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo empty($row['age']) ? 'null' : $row['age']
```

PS: avoid SQL Injection!